# Src path not working correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a bit of a silly problem but I'm not sure how can I get this to work. I'm storing an image path to the database in order to upload it into a folder.
This is the path I'm using to upload the file in that folder

```
$target_path = "../img/".$imagename;
```

I used this because the code file who does the uploading is in a folder called admin so I have to get back to the main folder where I have the img directory.

This is how I get the image path from database:

```
$select_img = "SELECT imgPath FROM  blog_images ORDER by imgID DESC";
$img_query = mysqli_query($link, $select_img) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($img_query);
```

Then I use the $row2 variable to access the imagepath.

Works great and the file is being uploaded there. However, when I tried to pull the image path from the database he goes back again and takes me to the localhost/img/example.jpg. I feel like I'm missing something.. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Post the code where you get the path from db

Comment: Here's the code I used to get the path.                                     $select_img = "SELECT imgPath FROM  blog_images ORDER by imgID DESC";
                                    $img_query = mysqli_query($link, $select_img) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($img_query); Then I just use the $row2 variable to access the path field. It takes the path correctly but when displayed in the src of the image it goes back to localhost

Comment: Edit the question and add the code into it.

Comment: I edited the post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
$target_path = "/img/".$imagename;
```

Store your path like this this will not go back.

Comment: It's not working if I change the path like that because I have the images folder outside of the admin folder where the php file that does the uploading is. He needs to know where to upload it and the upload works but when I pull it from database it takes me to localhost because of the path I initially set in order to get it uploaded in the correct place.